# Audio Streaming, NSTimer and parsing JSON scenario

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, parsing

Consider the following scenario.

An app that plays audio stream. Then there's the Now Playing view, which have the artist and song title, the album art of the current song and also the Producer's name, along side with small description and picture. All of which come from a JSON file.

In order to know when the JSON file has indeed been changed, there's an extra .crc file which contains the timestamp/code of the last changed JSON. When the content of the .crc has changed then it's time to update the JSON.

So I have an NSTimer firing every 10sec and opens an NSURLConnection which eventually returns the data of the .crc file. On the connectionDidFinish I check if the code has changed from the previous one and if the condition is true then I load the JSON and eventually parsing its data.

My question here is if this 10sec timer with the NSURLConnection is too much for the app?, having in mind that there's the constant audio stream playing. Of course when the app enters the background the timer stops. And then when the app enters the foreground I force load the JSON in order to update the view and start the timer again.

Also the now playing view is assigned to a self.nowplayingview ivar (created one time only) from the root view controller and the self.nowplayingview gets pushed to the stack. This way I can update the Now Playing view from the root view, when there's a change in the JSON.

Do you think that I should create and push the Now Playing view every time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would be better off using a NSThread than an NSTimer I think, so that the code to update the JSON still executes in the background.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII — Thanks I will try NSThread and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just modify the existing Now Playing View with the new information?  I also agree that this should probably either be done in a background thread (as Richard Ross has mentioned above), or ensure that the call is done asynchronously, so that it doesn't cause the app/interface to become sluggish and unresponsive.

Comment: Both calls for the .crc and the json file are asynchronous. I will try changing to NSThread instead of NSTimer to see how it goes. Thanks.